# MAC OS X Terminal force print f to ignore some variables

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, macos-sierra

i am experiencing a Problem with the printf function on MAC OS X terminal.
I already declared a variable and when i call it, it works. The problem is the following:

On the text i have some variables that start with "$" but belong to another system. I just want them to be printed on the file i am creating exactly this way ($foo) without bash trying to read them as its own variables. The result i get is an empty string.

I have the following code (dummy code):

```
echo "Type the wished folder name followed by [ENTER]:"

read baseName

echo '' > ext_emconf.php

printf " $VARIABLE[$ANOTHERVARIABLE] = [
'title' => '%s - Templates'
]; 
" $basename> ext_emconf.php
```

The result i get is this after the user gave for example "Amazon":

```
[] = [
    'title' => 'Amazon - Templates'
];
```

Although i was expecting:

```
$VARIABLE[$ANOTHERVARIABLE] = [
    'title' => 'Amazon - Templates'
];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no need to write a newline to the file before overwriting it with something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is double-quotes in `bash` tries to expand them as variables, but it has no definition for it. Use single quotes or better use here strings to print nice multi line formatted strings. Here is a sample way to do with some variables.

```
foo=bar
bar=foo
basename=foobar

tee ext_emconf.php <<EOF
$foo[$bar] = [
'title' => '$basename- Templates'
];
EOF
```

The above example uses `tee` to write both to stdout and to the file mentioned.  Also you can also just redirect stdout to `/dev/null` if you don't want it to be seen in console.

```
tee ext_emconf.php <<EOF > /dev/null
$foo[$bar] = [
'title' => '$basename- Templates'
];
EOF
```